# Minimum force required to push a car up a slope

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I have a problem calculating the force required to push my car up an inclined road.

My car has **1200** kg mass, the road angle is **4** degrees (7 percent slope) and static coefficient of friction between tires and dry asphalt is around **0.9**

The following picture is the forces acting on the car:

[image]

We have two negative forces that should be overcome in order for the car to start moving:

Force of friction $= \mu N = μs \cdot m g \cos \left( \theta \right)$

Resistive Force $= m g \sin \left( \theta \right)$

So, the minimum force required to push the vehicle up the hill $= μs \cdot m g \cos \left( \theta \right) + m g \sin \left( \theta \right) = 10559 + 820 = \mathbf{11379 N}$

Now, I calculate the maximum force acted by car tire on the ground.

1st gear ratio $= 3.455$

Final drive ratio $= 4.529$

Tire radius $= 0.289$ meter

Engine torque $= 155 nm$

Drivetrain loss = almost 10 percent (FWD)

Acceleration force $= \frac{Wheel ~ torque}{tire ~ radius} = \frac{2182}{0.289} = \mathbf{7553 N}$

========================================================

So, $\mathbf{7553} < \mathbf{11379}$ and it doesn't make sense at all because it means that my car can't even climb a 4 degrees slope with max force (torque) in 1st gear while I can even climb the same slope with 5th gear (let alone 1st!!!).

Why is there such a huge difference between my calculations and reality?

Comment: The tires have friction to the road, but what is the stiction drag to get it started then rolling drag.

Comment: Friction force at the tires only relates to the force applied by the tires. If the force applied by the tires is greater than the friction forces, then the tires will slip. If your wheels are locked and do not turn and you are pushing the vehicle up hill, then you need to overcome the friction forces to make the car slide up hill.

Comment: As mentioned, static friction means nothing (you're not sliding the tires).   If you really wanna know "exactly" the forces involved, you could try to obtain something like this --- https://www.amazon.com/Digital-Hanging-Aluminum-Handheld-Hunting/dp/B08KZRBTKL/ref=sr_1_3?crid=1OHHB7LQJ8676&keywords=rope+scale&qid=1647303570&sprefix=rope+scale%2Caps%2C122&sr=8-3  $$$$ Only $30 USD and it will read up to 3000 Newtons which (as per Davids answer) is well above 820N that is theoretically what you actually need.

Comment: @Kyle B - I have a digital hanging scale and I tried to pull my car on a level ground and it required around 20 kg to start moving but according to friction formula (μs⋅mgcos(θ), I need 1059 kg to pull the car!!! (0.9*1200*9.8066*1) = 10591 N!! (Cosine 0 = 1). 1059 kg means I need 30 people to push or pull the car on a level ground but I could do it alone with only 20 kg.

Comment: @Kyle B - Could you please explain to me why does static friction mean nothing? I have read in most physics articles that static friction is the negative force to overcome when a stationary object wants to move and in my example, the car is stationary too. I think this part needs more explanation.

Comment: The static friction will only be relevant if you put your car on handbrake when you're trying to pull it, since it means the tire won't rotate.

Comment: Hi Nariman Asgharian. Welcome to Phys.SE. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: @NarimanAsgharian   >>> Kyle B - Could you please explain to me why does static friction mean nothing? $$$$   Your car is not a block of wood.  It has wheels.  Static friction is what you get when surfaces slide against each other.  Your car has bearings and grease, it's made quite intentionally to minimize any friction.   There is no sliding (or almost none)

Comment: @Qmechanic - Hi Qmechanic (Sorry, I don't know your name). My question here is definitely not a homework question. I asked this question just out of curiosity to know how much force is needed to push my car in different slopes with varying angles. I'm 38 years old and not a student trying to cheat on assignments and exams! I'm interested in physics as a hobby. I hope you understand this!

Comment: @Kyle B - Thanks a million for your explanation. Now, I understand my mistake. Our parking ramp has a 15% slope. According to my calculations, I need 1917 N of force to push it up the ramp. If we assume an average adult can apply 350 N, then I need at least 6 people to do it! (Coefficient of Rolling resistance for tires ranges between 0.01 and 0.015 on dry asphalt).

Comment: Hi Nariman - our classification as a "homework-like" question refers more to the *content* of the question than to whether or not the question is *actual* homework. This is also discussed in the meta posts linked in the closing notice - questions of this kind are off-topic here regardless of the *intent* (e.g. cheating or not) behind asking them, since we cannot reliably determine intent anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resistive force in your analysis is the component of the gravitational force pulling the car down the incline (820 N).  You only have to overcome this force plus the tire rolling resistance of the car to push the car up the hill at very low speeds.

The force of friction in your analysis (10559 N) is the maximum force that the tires can apply to the road without slipping, and this force should not be included in your analysis.  Also note that it is very unclear how you calculated your "acceleration" force, as wheel torque just magically appeared in the analysis with no basis given.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Wheel torque is quite clear. It is engine torque x gear ratio x final drive ratio = 155 x 3.455 x 4.529 = 2425 nm and I assumed 10% drivetrain loss which means 2425 x 90/100 = 2182 nm at the wheels.

Comment: Why do you say static friction should not be included in my analysis? Isn't it true that static friction is the main force that you must overcome to get an object to move and then kinetic or rolling friction comes into play? So, static friction first, kinetic second. Shouldn't be like this? However, you say rolling resistance is enough. Rolling means moving. The tires of a stationary car are not rolling. It doesn't make sense.

Comment: The static friction force is the force that will move the car up the incline.  Once the static friction force exceeds 820 N, the car will have a net force up the incline, and will move up the incline.